# JMETER WebDriver - Dynamic Element with Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have copied the XML code here. And can you please advise the code from below sample? Thanks a lot

`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//li[contains(@id, 'cascader-menu')]/span[0]    ")).click();`

if hardcode like this "//li[@id='cascader-menu-9503-0-3']/span", it will work for the current webpage. But it don't work after reloaded.

Sample Code format: id="cascader-menu-8497-0-10"
id="cascader-menu-(Dynamic)-(0->2)-(1->10)"

`<div class="el-cascader-panel">`
`<div class="el-scrollbar el-cascader-menu" role="menu" id="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<div class="el-cascader-menu__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap" style="margin-bottom: -17px; margin-right: -17px;">`
`<ul class="el-scrollbar__view el-cascader-menu__list">`
`<li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-0" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node in-active-path" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0" aria-expanded="true">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">九龍</span><i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix">`
`</i>`
`</li>`
`<li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-1" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0"><span class="el-cascader-node__label">Australia</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li><li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-2" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">British Columbia</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix">`
`</i>`
`</li>`
`<li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-3" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">Greece</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li><li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-4" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">Hong Kong Island</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li><li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-5" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">Kowloon</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li><li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-6" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">New Territories</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li>`
`<li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-7" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">Singapore</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li>`
`<li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-8" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">Taiwan</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li><li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-9" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">UK</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li>`
`<li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-8497-0-10" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-8497-0">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">United States</span>`
`<i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li><svg class="el-cascader-menu__hover-zone">`
`<path style="pointer-events: auto;" fill="transparent" d="M-152 6 L183 0 V6 Z"></path>`
`<path style="pointer-events: auto;" fill="transparent" d="M-152 40 L183 187 V40 Z"></path>`
`</svg></ul></div><div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-horizontal"><div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateX(0%);">`
`</div>`
`</div>`
`<div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-vertical">`
`<div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateY(0%); height: 48.4456%;">`
`</div></div></div><div class="el-scrollbar el-cascader-menu" role="menu" id="cascader-menu-4173-1">`
`<div class="el-cascader-menu__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap" style="margin-bottom: -17px; margin-right: -17px;">`
`<ul class="el-scrollbar__view el-cascader-menu__list">`
`<li role="menuitem" id="cascader-menu-4173-1-0" tabindex="-1" class="el-cascader-node" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="cascader-menu-4173-1">`
`<span class="el-cascader-node__label">九龍東</span><i class="el-icon-arrow-right el-cascader-node__postfix"></i>`
`</li><svg class="el-cascader-menu__hover-zone">`
`<path style="pointer-events: auto;" fill="transparent" d="M178.40625 6 L207 0 V6 Z"></path>`
`<path style="pointer-events: auto;" fill="transparent" d="M178.40625 40 L207 187 V40 Z"></path>`
`</svg>`
`</ul>`
`</div>`
`<div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-horizontal">`
`<div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateX(0%);">`
`</div>`
`</div>`
`<div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-vertical">`
`<div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateY(0%);">`
`</div>`
`</div>`
`</div>`
`</div>`
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's not XML, it's [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)
2. It doesn't contain the element you're looking for

Whatever, you can stick to text of the location like:

```
//span[text()='Shaukeiwan`]
```

Prior to that you might need to click this `Hong Kong Island` followed by `Mid Level North Point` and don't forget to use [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) to ensure that the element is available/visible/can be clicked

You can see [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article for example implementation.

Comment: The method works perfect. Thanks so much.